# Pure Data: Dynamically route an audio signal to different channels

Tags: audio, puredata

I'm using Pure Data for a project where I'll be playing several audio files at the same time to different speakers.

Let's say I have two files, and I want one to be played on the left channel of the soundcard, and the second one on the right channel, so that's the first and second inlet of the `dac~ 1 2` object.

How can I route the audio signal depending on another value?

I'm basically looking for something like the `route` object, but with some extra parameter, or some way to pack the audio signal with the channel number (1, 2) and use the number to route the signal.

I just found out that Yves Degoyon's "unauthorized" library has the `spigot~` object that does what I want, but only with two channels. In the end I would like to be able to output different sounds to eight or nine channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[demultiplex~]** from the Zexy library to route one incoming signal to one of several outlets. For instance, **[demultiplex~ 1 2 3 4]** will have one inlet and four outlets. The single inlet takes both an incoming signal (which will be routed) as well as an single float which selects the outlet to which the signal will be routed. For the opposite behaviour (several incoming signals to several inlets, and only one of them being output by the single outlet) try **[multiplex~]**.

Also note that you can use **[mux~]** and **[demux~]** as they are aliases for these same objects.

Comment: btw, `[demux~]` is part of *zexy* rather than *Pd-extended*; Pd-extended comes with *zexy* preinstalled, but there are many different ways to install it...

Comment: @umläute I edited the answer and removed the reference to Pd-extended

Answer (score 3):

Pd-extended is not maintained any more. You can install **Zexy** for Vanilla Pd via the Debian package or the **Deken** plugin. Then you will have the `demultiplex~` object available. However, there might be good reasons why you might not wanting to use an external at all. Here is one way to patch a kind of a switchboard. Additional benefit: You can specify your favorite fade time and type.

[image: Switchboard]

Comment: I didn't know you could install external packages on vanilla PD. Is it a problem that Pd-extended isn't maintained anymore? I think I prefer some aspects of the UI…
As for the solution you suggest, I thought about something similar but didn't find something clean and functional. Thanks!

Comment: "However, there might be good reasons why you might not wanting to use an external at all." Can you give some of those reasons? I have never ever head of anyone advocating one to avoid externals in Pd. Also, one clear advantage of using **[demux~]** is that it dynamically creates as many inlets as you entered as arguments

Comment: @Niavlys "Is it a problem that Pd-extended isn't maintained anymore?" It's not a problem, except that you won't ever get bugs fixed (and there are some of them) nor will you get newer objects that are shipped with newer vanilla. If you are on Linux, I recommend taking a look on a third distribution of Pd called Pd-l2Ork (and which may soon be released for OSX and maybe Windows). Its GUI is fantastic and it is very well maintained.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f Sure, here are three:1. you want to create a patch that has no, or minimized dependencies, so it is easier to be opened by others. 2. you want to run your patch on another device, maybe with libpd and you don't want to ship another library with it. 3. you want to deploy your project with a license that the external conflicts with (a commercial project for example, where you don't want to publish all the source).

Comment: Sure, those are reasonable arguments. I was thinking you meant something related to programming itself, in the sense of how externals work as opposed to how abstractions work. So yeah, if those things you listed are one's concern, then you are 100% right.

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f I think it might be even possible to patch a [demux~] with the dynamically created number of in and outlets. Current vanilla has [clone] that can help you.

Comment: @MaxN [clone] won't help you here; with Pd-0.47-0 we finally have `[initbang]` that allows you to create `[demux~]` as an abstraction - but `[initbang]` is only available as an external :-(

Answer (score 0):

Based on Max N answer, you can also use a toggle to modify the volume of the signal and know where it redirects :

[image: example]

In this case, if the toggle is active, the signal will be sent on the left outlet. If it is inactive, the right outlet will receive the signal.

Comment: Instead of [expr 1 - $f1] you can also simply use a [== 0]. Be aware that this solution will be hard switching the audio without and fade time. This may cause pops.